# Putting TeamCity build number into the assemblies it build

Tags: teamcity

I am new to TeamCity and I have just installed it and set it up with subversion.
I would like the TeamCity build number to be put in the output files, so that my Application.exe has the same build number.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is now an assemblyinfo patcher built into teamcity. They call it a build feature: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/AssemblyInfo+Patcher

Use that with the parameters mention or make your own e.g.: 1.2.%build.vcs.number%.1

Answer (score 3):

try this:

- [Team City - Update AssemblyInfo with current build number](http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2008/06/team-city-update-assemblyinfo-with.html)

This is using Team City with MSBuild.  If you're using Nant try this:

- [Getting the TeamCity build number into the AssemblyInfo file using Nant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387878/getting-the-teamcity-build-number-into-the-assemblyinfo-file-using-nant)

Comment: Nice finds. Thanks. Often I compile locally, does this require me to have TC and MSBuild Community Tasks/NAnt installed locally as well as on the TC server?

Comment: This method doesn't change the AssemblyInfo.cs file until build time, so building anywhere else will not be affected.  Obviously there will be no build number added if you build locally.

Comment: But won't it fail the build if I don't have the necessary build tools installed locally, or will it just ignore $(BUILD_NUMBER) etc.?

Comment: `$(BUILD_NUMBER)` is in the msbuild file. I don't know how you do your Team City builds but in my setup I don't use msbuild files for my local setup ( I just build with Visual Studio).  if you do then you'll need to have separate files for local and build machine or something.

Comment: -1 should at least provide context that this is a lowest common denominator answer to the problem. TeamCity has an AssemblyInfo patcher build task, which is the easy path.

Answer (score 1):

I run a powershell script after getting the sources from svn and before the build starts.

More or less like so.

http://jake.murzy.com/post/3099699807/how-to-update-assembly-version-numbers-with-teamcity